# Spring v3 no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, schema

### Currently Running

Tomcat: v6

Spring Tools Suite: v2.7.2

Spring Framework: spring-webmvc-3.0.5

### Servlet XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

      <mvc:annotation-driven />

      <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />

      <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.mvc" />

 </beans>
```

### web.xml partial code

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>duckapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### Servlet Purpose

web.xml maps all urls to the servlet with the exception of mvc:resources mapping static files.

### Bugs

- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.    app-servlet.xml /app/www/WEB-INF
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.    app-servlet.xml /app/www/WEB-INF

### Known Issues

- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd doesn't contain the element resource
- If replaced by http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd still doesn't work and may not be working according to jar files of spring 3.05
- mvc:resources appeared in spring v3.0.4, but has no new xsd

### Question

How can I fix the compile errors to get mvc:resources working correctly?

I've been digging around 2 hours for this, no solid answer yet...

Comment: I don't think it is desirable to use version in xsd declaration. Spring will use highest version in the project's dependencies if version not given.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your spring context xml mvc namespace url should match url in schemaLocation. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

This is a standard XML namespace declaration. The namespace url is sort of an unique id, which is then mapped to the actual schema location in xsi:schemaLocation.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. I wish this was better documented in Spring

Comment: Doesnt work. i have the exact same problem but using spring 3.1

Comment: The only thing you need to change in above snippet is version of spring-mvc.xsd - http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd

Comment: in that case try the below one  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 I had the same problem and this solved it ..

Comment: You should (almost) never use versioned schema. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version/20900801#20900801

Answer (score 6):

When using Spring namespaces urls I normally do not use version information and that
works most of the time pretty well.
You might like to try the namespace url

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
```

instead of

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

Comment: I don't think it is desirable to use version in xsd declaration. Spring will use highest version in the project's dependencies if version not given.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. The cause was the missing Maven dependency spring -webmvc. I included the below dependency and it started working.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your schemaLocation mapping is incorrect. The namespace is specified as:

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

which is correct, I believe, but in the schemaLocation you have

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

So if you change the first line of the schemaLocation mapping to your mvc namespace, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have enroled for spring course on udemy. I followed every step that my instructor show me to do.
So if you are using spring mvc and hibernate you may encounter this error
Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd' etc for:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/> and <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" /> elements
```

in my spring configuration file i had these two urls

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
```

in xsi:schemaLocation, which i replaced with

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
```

actually i visited these two sites
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/ and http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/
and just added the latest version of spring-mvc and spring-tx i.e, spring-mvc-4.2.xsd  and  spring-tx-4.2.xsd

So, in my opinion specifying version no explicitly is a good practice.
It worked for me, hope this works for you too.
Thank you.