# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'resources'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I know this is a duplicate and you people are gonna chide me for it, but I didn't get a proper solution after reading all the posts.
I am trying to build a Spring Template application in Spring Source Tool Suite.
I am getting the following error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 16 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'resources'.

My root-context.xml is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache http://www.springmodules.org/schema/cache/springmodules-ehcache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

</beans>
```

Please let me know if there is a jar file missing in my application.
These are the only jar files I have in my application:
displaytag-1.0-b3.jar, spring-2.0.6.jar, spring-asm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-hibernate3-2.0.8.jar, spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar & spring-webmvc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar

Here is my servlet-context.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.controller" />



</beans:beans>
```

Please help...it's really annoying.

Comment: Why didn't you post the actual XML, including the "resources" element?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I really don't understand which xml file you are talking about. This context.xml is what I have got. With this file in place there is the error which I have mentioned.

Comment: The error is about an element "`resources`", which presumably occurs in your XML.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for the quick response. There is no such element in my xml, you spotted it. But I don't know if there is such an element to be added to the xml file. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Show your /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml file.

Comment: The problem report complains about an **existing** element "resources", not a missing one. I don't see how you can get that error without an actual element.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks. Here it is 
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Comment: Please post the relevant XML file, up to line 16, **in your question** by editing it. Not in a comment like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring v3 no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436224/spring-v3-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-mvcresources)

Comment: You have declared namespace prefixes that you fail to use for the elements. It's `<mvc:resources>`, as seen in the duplicate question I linked to above. The same goes for your other elements.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry for being a dumbhead, I don't understand the above comment. Where do I have to add the <mvc:resources> ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Pressure is building on my head. Please explain the last comment. The error I have made may be silly, but I am unable to spot it.

Comment: Your XML is correct, but your Spring version is too old...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your XML is fine, but according to [this comment on a SpringSource blog post about Spring MVC 3](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/#comment-174486)

> The `<mvc:resources/>` tag is a new feature coming in Spring Framework 3.0.4

Your application uses Spring 3.0.3, so you need to upgrade to 3.0.4 or later to be able to use the resources tag.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I tried changing the tag to <mvc:resouces mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> but still I am getting an error.

Comment: Robert Now should I upgrade my jar files to spring 3.0.4 or change any tag? Please help...

Comment: @Freakyuser your XML was correct in the first place, you are using an XML element with the local name `resources` and the namespace URI `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc` (using that as the default namespace of your XML file instead of the more usual approach of using the "beans" namespace as the default and mapping the MVC namespace to a prefix, but from an XML point of view both approaches are equivalent).  But 3.0.3 does not support this element at all, you must upgrade in order to make it work.