# external javascript not working with spring

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I am working with spring 3 framework for developing my web application. I have to link my external javascript file with my jsp forms. For this i am using script tag as follows:
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>`

My web.xml mapping is as follows:

```
`<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
```

But i am getting error like this:

> Mar 13, 2014 4:54:01 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Project/test.js] in >DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Here is my workspace structure. Project>>WebContent>>jsp

And in the jsp folder, i am having all the jsp's and test.js file.

I had tried
 - changing the web.xml configuration
 - tried getting context path with test.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/test.js"></script>
```

- tried pasting the test.js file in different paths
- created a directory inside webcontent and pasted test.js file to check

  `<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/jsp/test.js"></script>`

I have referred many of related post, but i could not resolve it till now. Please somebody who had same issue help to resolve this.

**EDIT**
Here i am adding my spring-servlet.xml for reference.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.inet.test.spring3.controller" />  

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You dont want to specify it under `<server-mapping>`. Specify it in html code

Comment: if you are using spring specify it in applicationcontext file

Comment: can you update your question with your dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: @Pilot i wrote the <script> tag in my html page only. I added web.xml for reference purpose. I din't add any <script> tag in that. Hope i am getting you.

Comment: @VasudevPathak Are you mentioning spring-servlet.xml. Sorry, i am new to spring. Kindly clarify me.

Comment: yes, your mapping should be in spring-servlet.xml with resources mapping annotation

Comment: @VasudevPathak Thanks. I have edited the post to add spring-servlet.xml file.

Comment: <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>  use this to mapping .   Map with js folder...i hope it will help you

Comment: @VasudevPathak I had tried that already. <mvc:resources/> tag will work after spring 3.0.4 versions only. Anyway thanks for your help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645792/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-re)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't have to define servlet-mapping to include external java script file.

Remove

```
<servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Replace with

```
<servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Configure your **@RequestMapping("/mycontroller.html")**

By giving **/** you configured the spring to handle all request coming to the application. In this case you did not have  proper handler for .js files.

By giving ***.do** you configured the spring to handle only request that ends only with .do

Comment: Thanks @Shakthydoss. I understand <url-pattern> pretty clear now. Also  changed "/" to *.do now and its working like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, whenever a url in your domain ends with .js, it will be mapped to your

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

I was thinking, why do you need to map *.js? Is there any reason? Could you try removing that servlet-mapping tag and try again?

Comment: I thought it would map all js files. Sorry if am wrong. And tried removing that from web.xml. Still its not working. I got same error. >Mar 14, 2014 9:53:02 AM >org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI >[/Project/test.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: Oh strange. Did u recompile after removing the .js mapping? Your error message still saying that .js is going to DispatcherServlet and no mapping is found for test.js.

Comment: You really don't have to define servlet-mapping to include external java script file.