# Spring 3 Interceptors Error: Type Element type "beans" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am new to Spring 3 MVC and trying to implement `Interceptors` in an example by following this URL as a reference:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

I am getting the above error in the spring-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.spring.controller" />

<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean class="com.spring.interceptor.HelloWorldInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>    
     <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
```

I am getting that error in this line:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: What's where the `......` are?

Comment: You haven't closed somewhere tag `/>`

Comment: I have added the full code. Please let me know on this

Comment: Are you sure you've given the full code?  Where's the ending `</bean>` tag for the `jspViewResolver` bean?

Comment: Yes, I do have `</bean>` and `</beans>` at the end. Moreover, can you please guide me on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below thread has resolved the issue, hence closing this thread as well.

[Spring v3 no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436224/spring-v3-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-mvcresources)

Answer (score 0):

Please close your bean definition

```
  <bean id="jspViewResolver" 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"/>
```