# Spring MVC is not recognizing mvc:resource in config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Update :Now Working properly. Kindly follow the comments. 
This is my Spring configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    ">
    <context:component-scan  base-package="report.frontcontroller"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/</value></property>
        <property name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

All jars are included in this project, and the configuration file is shown above. I get errors for this part:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

> **Errors:**  * Matching wildcard is strict but no declaration is found for `mvc:resource` and `mvc:annotation`
>     *** Multiple annotations found at this line:**
>       - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.
>       - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-
>        mvc-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document 
>        is not .
>    **Multiple annotations found at this line:***
>       - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.
>       - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-
>        mvc.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document 
>        is not .

Comment: The configuration file itself is correct. What is your Spring (MVC) version?

Comment: Which spring jars do you have in your application?

Comment: its spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources and all others jars are of same version too.

Comment: Now Running
The problem was with the ips ie blocking the request for 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd file. 
There are two solutions for it either download it on local and include it on classpath or ask network engineer for not blocking the request.

Comment: This file is included in spring jars already. You most likely have a dependency issue in your project.

Answer (score 0):

can you try below configuration that is copied from [GIT - spring-mvc-showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <task:annotation-driven />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Still same issue..
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.
 - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-
  mvc-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document 
  is not <xsd:schema>.

Comment: Now Running
The problem was with the ips ie blocking the request for 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd file. 
There are two solutions for it either download it on local and include it on classpath or ask network engineer for not blocking the request.

Comment: This file is included in spring jars. You probably have a classpath or version conflict issue.

Answer (score 0):

don't use the version number just do the following steps.
In eclipse we didn't enable the download package option.
eclipse download packages option is in disable, to enable that follow these
windows menu - > preferences -> maven
there check(enable) the 'download artifact javadoc' option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

change to `spring-mvc.xsd` to `spring-mvc-3.0.xsd` .Similarly change at all the remaining places too.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436224/spring-v3-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-mvcresources)

**Edit**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="report.frontcontroller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I am using spring-mvc-4.1.1.  According the documents we have to use same version of jars.

Comment: Yeah.. that's not the point I wanted to highlight giving you the link. Its the bugs in spring that were reported in that thread. Anyway changing the xsd to as suggested above will resolve your issue.

Comment: So do i need to downgrade all the jars or will it work only by changing in configuration file. Because its not working as you suggested above.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b568mxps1e93pww/Screenshot%20from%202015-02-04%2017%3A03%3A43.png?dl=0

Kindly refer the above link. It still having the same issue.

Comment: just try the web.xml config i updated in the edit section , I am using spring 4.1 and that is my spring-context.xml ... i have changed the base package.. so you can copy paste and try...

Comment: Now Running
The problem was with the ips ie blocking the request for 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd file. 
There are two solutions for it either download it on local and include it on classpath or ask network engineer for not blocking the request.

Comment: you should always use versionless schemas! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894695/spring-configuration-xml-schema-with-or-without-version/20900801#20900801

Comment: @BrianClozel hey.. I just posted a solution that solved my problem .. I had the same problem.. Now to use it or not or the best practice is a different scenario .. There are solutions posted here and the user has to compare and choose the best one.. downvoting on that context is just plainly wrong.